# SQL CE DISTINCT AGGREGATE

Tags: sql, aggregate, distinct

Does SQL CE has the ability to use distinct in aggregate functions?
I need something like

```
SELECT count(distinct date) FROM table
```

This is simplified query and I already have GROUP BY used in original one.

Answer (score 5):

SQL Server CE (current version) does not support count(distinct)

The workaround is a GROUP BY, which sounds like what you are using

```
select count(*) from (
    select distinct date from tbl
) x
```

Or if other fields are involved

```
select groupcol, count(*)
from (
    select groupcol, date
    from tbl
    group by groupcol, date
) x
group by groupcol
```